# why I can not directly get the value from shared memory using a pointer

Tags: c, shared-memory

to direct access the X$Table in SGA, I get the current address of C struct(also is the X$table of oracle in SGA memory) is 0x00000001860CD020; and obtain the offset of field 'KSUSSSEQ' is 5824,size is 2. so i write C code to get the KSUSSSEQ as `seq = *(unsigned short *)((char *) current_addr+KSUSSSEQ);` .in my code the value is 21061, but the true val is 0. so I wonder whether I get a wrong value based on address+offset. below is the C code and base address and offset info.
the current_addr in code is the start address of the first records in x$ksusecst;the offset of field 'KSUSSSEQ'  is query from oracle, I direct access the SGA memory with shmat(); the 'KSUSSSEQ' val in oracle is 0 but in my code is 21061.
below is my C code and some info about X$table KSUSSSEQ field in orcle

```
 #include <sys/ipc.h>
 #include <sys/shm.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include "events.h"
 #define SGA_BASE         0X0000000060000000
 #define KSUSECST_ADDR    0X00000001860CD020
 #define KSUSECST_SESSION 1524
 #define KSUSECST_RD_SZ   12512
 #define KSUSSSEQ         5824     /* offset 5824  size 2 */                             
 #define KSUSSOPC         5826     /* offset 5826  size 2 */                             
 #define KSUSSP1R         5832     /* offset 5832  size 8 */                             
 #define KSUSEP2R         5840     /* offset 5840  size 8 */                             
 #define KSUSEP3R         5848     /* offset 5848  size 8 */                              
 

void *sga_attach (void *addr, int shmid)
{

     if ( addr != 0 ) addr=(void *)shmdt(addr);
     addr=(void *)shmat(shmid,(void *)SGA_BASE,SHM_RDONLY);
     if (addr  == (void *)-1) {
         printf("shmat: error attatching to SGA\n");
         exit(1);
     } else {
        printf("address %lx %lu\n",(int *)addr,(long *)addr);
     }
     return addr;
}

 main(argc, argv)
 int argc;
 char **argv;
 {
  void  *addr;
  int   shmid;
  long  p1r, p2r, p3r;
  unsigned int   seq,i,env;
  char * current_addr;
  unsigned short* seqoffset; 

  shmid=atoi(argv[1]);
  addr=sga_attach(addr,shmid);
  while(1) {
    current_addr = (void *) KSUSECST_ADDR;
    
    printf("%4s%10s%56.56s%7s%10s%10s%10s\n","sid","seq","event_name","event#","p1(HEX)","p2(HEX)","p3(HEX)");
    printf("%s\n","-----------------------");
    for(i=0; i<KSUSECST_SESSION; i++) {
        short *seqp = (unsigned short *)(current_addr+KSUSSSEQ);
        seq = *(unsigned short *)( current_addr+KSUSSSEQ);
        short * envp = (short *)(current_addr+KSUSSOPC);
        env = *(short *)(current_addr+KSUSSOPC);
        p1r = *(long *)(current_addr+KSUSSP1R);
        p2r = *(long *)(current_addr+KSUSEP2R);
        p3r = *(long *)(current_addr+KSUSEP3R);
        
        if(env!=0) {
            printf("%4d %6d %8d %10X %10X %10X\n", (i+1),seq,env,p1r,p2r,p3r);
        }
        current_addr = (void *)((char *)current_addr + KSUSECST_RD_SZ);
    }
    sleep(1); 
  }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not post pictures of code or text. Instead, copy and paste the text into your question and either indent by 4-spaces so it formats as fixed text (with highlighting) or include `\`\`\`` (3 back-ticks) on the line above and below your text block to format as fixed text as well.

Comment: thanks for you advice I had changed the question

Comment: `main(argc, argv) int argc; char **argv;` Where did you get that one? K&R declaration style is a thing of past centuries. Same as "implicit int" rule.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour: `addr=sga_attach(addr,shmid);` here `addr` is not inititlized and contains indetermined value. You check the content in `sga_attac` which can easily contain some nun-NULL random garbage which you interpret as a valid pointer.

Comment: but this place looks like not a primary question for my question.  could this place  effect  ```seq = *(unsigned short *)( current_addr+KSUSSSEQ);```  ?